# How to set Current_company_flag using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a model for storing Experience...

Here is my model

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    current_company = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

In this current_company is used to showing it is the current company ....

This is my form for getting the data from user

```
class  ExperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Experience
        exclude = ['user']
```

This is my view

```
class ExperienceFormView(TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile/expereince_form.html'
    form_class = ExperienceForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if context['form'].is_valid():
            data = context['form'].save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Created Successfully'}, status=201, safe=False)
        return super(ExperienceFormView, self).render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExperienceFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = ExperienceForm(
            self.request.POST or None)  # instance= None
        context["form"] = form
        return context
```

What is the best way to implment the following use cases

1) If I enable my current_company as True then the previous object having current_company becomes False

2)If there is no previous object then ignore the first use case.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `Experience` objects related to the user such that `current_company` is `False` with a query:

```
class ExperienceFormView(TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile/expereince_form.html'
    form_class = ExperienceForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if context['form'].is_valid():
            data = context['form'].save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            if data.current_company:
                Experience.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(current_company=False)
            data.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Created Successfully'}, status=201, safe=False)
        return super(ExperienceFormView, self).render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExperienceFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = ExperienceForm(
            self.request.POST or None)  # instance= None
        context["form"] = form
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ExperienceFormView.post()` you'll want to do a search for that user's Experience... in the `form.is_valid()` part. Something like

```
current_experience = Experience.objects.filter(user=request.user, current_company=True)
if current_experience:
    current_experience.current_company = False
    current_company.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ExperienceManager class to Experience. Managers let you perform operations on django models at the level of the query set, which seems appropriate since you need access to the Experience siblings to turn the previous to false. When you use Experince.objects.all(), for example, "objects" is the default manager class. Here is how you can define your own.

```
class ExperienceManager( models.Manager ):

    #self is of type objects in Experience.objects.
    def getOrderedExpereince( self ): 
        experiences = self.all()
        experiences = orderExp( experiences ) # whatever your criteria for sorting
        return experiences
    def updateActiveExperience( self, experience ):
        experiences = self.getOrderedExperiences()
        currentIndex = [ i for i, exp in enumerate(experiences) if exp == experience]
        if currentIndex: currentIndex = currentIndex[0]
        experiences[i] = True
        experiences[i].save()
        experiences[i-1] = False
        experiences[i-1].save()
        return experiences # or whatever
class Experience( models.Model ):
    mymanager = ExperienceManager()
    ....
```

Then in your forms you can say

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if context['form'].is_valid():
            data = context['form'].save(commit=False)

            #Added this line
            data.mymanager.updateActiveCompany(data)
            data.user = request.user
            data.save()
```

Note I didn't check run the above but it is something close to that.